# Matplotlib svg output exhibits odd behavior

Tags: python, svg, matplotlib

I am making a polar plot of wind distribution over a time period and I am saving it in svg format to include it in a figure i'm making in inkscape.

Here is an example of my data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Theta =  np.asanyarray([11.25,  33.75,  56.25,  78.75, 101.25, 123.75, 146.25, 168.75,
              191.25, 213.75, 236.25, 258.75, 281.25, 303.75, 326.25])

R = np.asanyarray([5.4,2.4,1.2,2.6,5.4,2.3,5.8,5.4,3.3,1.8,1.0,4.0,13.1,7.6,3.2])

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 1,subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'},figsize = (2,2))

axes.set_theta_direction(-1)
axes.set_theta_offset(0)
axes.set_theta_zero_location('N')
axes.set_thetagrids([0,90,180,270],['N','E','S','W'])
axes.bar((Theta)*np.pi/180,R,width=2*np.pi/Theta.shape[0],edgecolor='black')
plt.savefig('Plot1.svg')
```

When I just run it like this everything works fine.  However, theta in my data set represents the bin centers, while it is plotted as the bin edges, so I'd like to subtract half the bin width so it aligns with the proper wind direction

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 1,subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'},figsize = (2,2))
axes.set_theta_direction(-1)
axes.set_theta_offset(0)
axes.set_theta_zero_location('N')
axes.set_thetagrids([0,90,180,270],['N','E','S','W'])
axes.bar((Theta-11.25)*np.pi/180,R,width=2*np.pi/Theta.shape[0],edgecolor='black')
plt.savefig('Plot2.svg')
```

The only difference between the two plots is the subtraction of a constant from Plot2.  However, when I import them into inkscape they are very different sizes.

[image]

Plot 1 is (2 in x 2 in) as I specified, but for some reason Plot 2 is (38.357 in x 2 in)?  Additionally, the resulting files are different sizes 147 kb for Plot 1 vs 145 kb for Plot 2.  However, if I save them as .png files instead, they both maintain the proper dimensions and are the same file size.

I can clip it in inkscape and work around the issue, but I'd just like to know why it is happening so I can prevent it in the future??

Comment: I just copied your code and ran it in python 2.7. Using matplotlib 2.0, both plots have the same filesize (141kB) and svg figure size. Using matplotlib 1.5, Plot1.svg has 151kB and Plot2.svg has148 kB. But they both have the same figure size in the svg file. Conclusion: I cannot reproduce this issue.

Comment: I am also unable to reproduce your issue using python 3.5 and matplotlib 1.5. Is this an issue with loading the svg into Inkscape?